# Passing a parameter to through a 3rd party function with a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, parameter-passing

I'm trying to do something like the following sample based off [mastering-javascript-callbacks-bind-apply-call](https://thenewstack.io/mastering-javascript-callbacks-bind-apply-call/). I have a class which manages a callback, it gets triggered, and I want to trigger some code from inside the class again. In the example I bind an extra variable into the class 'this' when defining the callback so that when the callback is triggered is can still call functions from within the class. All of this works fine.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env node

class Doge {
    constructor(callback) {
        // bind an extra variable to the callback that represent the class instance 'this' context
        let boundCallback = callback.bind({doge: this});

        // associate the callback with the class
        this.callback = boundCallback;
    }

    // a way to initiate the callback (would normally be triggered with getting data for instance)
    doCallback(data) {
        this.callback(data);    
    }

    // something inside the class we want to get
    getSaying() {
        return "Such callback!";    
    }
}

//callback normally only gets one variable (i.e. the incoming data), but we've been sneaky and associated some data
// in the this context ...which was the this from the class instance
function callback(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(this.doge.getSaying()); 
}

// creates class instance andsets the callback function (which is not in the class)
var doge = new Doge(callback); 

// call the callback with some data
doge.doCallback("test");
```

I thought this would simulate a 3rd party function initiating the callback as a means to pass knowledge of the class instance to the callback (since ths function that triggers the callback changes the 'this' context), but I was wrong or made a mistake.

My real example uses the web socket library (ws). I tried to implement a similar concept and it complains because the 'stream_this' I bound to the socketCallback is gone.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

module.exports = class Stream {

    constructor(socket_url) {
        //we want to store data unique to the class instance here
        this.stream_data = {}
        this.ws = new WebSocket(socket_url);

        let boundCallback = socketCallback.bind({stream_this: this});
        this.callback = boundCallback;

        this.ws.on('message', boundCallback); // <--- callback association
    }

    addChannels(channels) {
        var self = this;

        this.ws.on('open', function open() {    
            self.ws.send(JSON.stringify(channels, null, 4));
        });           
    }

}

function socketCallback(data) {
    var self = this;
    var response = JSON.parse(data);  // turn the string back to JSON

    // primative response processor
    response.forEach(function(result) {

        if (result.channel == "addChannel") {
            // confirm the channel is subscribed too     
        } else {
            // associate data with the class instance somehow
            this.stream_this.stream_data[result.timestamp] = result.data  <- this.stream is undefined.
        }

    });
}
```

How can I pass knowledge to the callback of the class instance so that I can access variables and functions of the class instance from within the callback? I know I could do this by removing the class and having a global variable for the data I wanted to store, but then the code is not re-entrant for multiple stream instances I might manage in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to the problem using the same method. The socketCallback needed to be inside the class. Once it was

```
this.stream_this
```

works and can access the class instance.